# Conditional Expectation and Variance with Multiple Conditions

Tags: conditional-expectation

Question on the properties of conditional expectation - Is it true that $E [W(t) | W(s) - W(u)] = E[W(t) | W(s), W(u)]$ ?

Context - To prove that for a Wiener process $W(t)$, $E[W(t) | W(s),W(u)] = W(s) + ((t-s)/(u-s))(W(u) - W(s))$

Thanks

Comment: In general, it is _not_ true that $E[W(t)\mid W(s) - W(u)] = E[W(t) \mid W(s), W(u)]$. Note that the right side of the equation that you are really trying to prove, _viz._ $$E[W(t)\mid W(s),W(u)]=W(s)+((t−s)/(u−s))(W(u)−W(s))\tag{1}$$ is _not_ a function of $W(s)-W(u)$, and so even if the result that you are wondering about is true, it does not help in establishing $(1)$.